# How many websites do I need to make for mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm building a website, and I found a crazy number of favicon sizes to be pertinent for most devices. Really pretty ridiculous. I any event, I understand how to make my HTML read the viewport size and redirect to other HTML docs and stylesheets as needed, but my question is, how many is needed in this world of 30+ different screen sizes?

Is Bootstrap all I need? I imagine bootstrap is mostly about percentages (`height: 5vh; width: 100vw;`) etc. Seems easy enough to redo my current desktop site to a tablet and iPhone size screen, but if this is anything like the favicon ordeal, then it would be easier to use something like Bootstrap.

Comment: Go read th Bootstrap docs, there's enough in there to get started. Other than that, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I hardly doubt it's off topic as there was a similar question about favicon that got 300+ useful hits.

Comment: But you're not asking a specific question, it's a broad sweep which requires a long non-specific answer and is entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ONE website, and you need to use media queries in it - depending on how picky you are, a usual way is to create them for three sizes - one set of basic rules and two sets in media queries (though these only have to contain those rules that differ from the basic rules) for the other sizes (i.e. smartphone, tablet, desktop). (favicons are a different thing).

Bootstrap can be helpful with that, but doesn't  have advantages only.